# How to find the SUM of scores and store it in new column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created a matching game and stored it score in the database. So every time a user finishes the game, his score is updated in the database replacing the old score.The problem is, I wanted to add the new score with the old score and save it in a new column. I tried something like the below code:

```
if(isset($_POST['gamescore'])){
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$fetch = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$fetchid =mysqli_query($db, $fetch);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($fetchid)){
  $id = $row['id'];
  $username=$row['username'];
  $gamescore= $_POST['gamescore'];
  $updatescore= "UPDATE users SET score='$gamescore' WHERE id = '$id'";
  mysqli_query($db, $updatescore);
  $addscore= "SELECT sum(score='$gamescore') AS sum_score FROM users WHERE id='$id'";
  mysqli_query($db,$addscore);
  $finalscore="UPDATE sum_score SET sum_score = sum(score='$gamescore') WHERE id='$id'";
  mysqli_query($db,$finalscore);
 }
 }
```

when I run the above code, score column gets updated by the new score, each time the player finishes the game but the sum of the old score and new score is not happening, I would appreciate if someone could help me with this problem.

The database table has columns "username", "id" , "password", "score" and "sum_score".

Comment: Please be aware that you should **NEVER** use user input directly in SQL statements! You should use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead, binding your `$_POST` variables to parameters. Given your code above, you have a serious security vulnerability -- a malicious user could easily `DROP` your entire database (or possibly even create a backdoor). You can refer to [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) for further information on how to prevent SQL injection in PHP :)

Comment: First, use prepared statements.  There are SQL injection problems all over your code snip-it.  `UPDATE users SET sum_score = (sum_score + $gamescore) WHERE id='$id'` should do the trick. You do not need the select statement `$addscore`

Comment: @AlexBarker thank you , the code works now. I will change the queries to avoid SQL injections

Comment: Do you really have multiple rows in the `users` table with the same username? If not, why are you using a loop to fetch all of them?

Comment: Is the `sum_score` column in the `users` table or a separate `sum_score` table? The `UPDATE sum_score` query means that it's a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything in your code with one query. As has been mentioned in the comments, you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to protect yourself from [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). Try something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['gamescore'])) {
    $sql = "UPDATE users
            SET score = ?,
                sum_score = sum_score + ?
            WHERE username = ?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("iis", $_POST['gamescore'], $_POST['gamescore'], $_SESSION['username'])l
    $stmt->execute();
}
```